# Does the command vite start have some advantages over node ./index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm launching a new SvelteKit app for production and came across the `vite start` command.

I'm always starting the app with node `file.js`.

Does the vite command have extra advantages over basic node?

I'm not getting any wiser by the documentation or source code.

Comment: It's totally different thing

Comment: btw you can omit `.js` and use `node index` or `node file`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski tell me :) what I can tell it's both starting the app

Comment: What does your `index.js` look like then?

Answer (score 0):

Vite provides a development server which is optimized for quick development and iteration.

The main advantages probably are:

- Fast startup because it does not bundle the code first
- Parts of the running application can be updated via Hot Module Replacement (e.g. a Svelte component)
- Related to that: Automatic update of the page when a module is replaced